# create email address from columns in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i made a table with names ,family names and mail provider. now i want to create a mail address from those. how can i do that?

here's what the table looks like at the moment:

```
+----------+-------------+---------------+
|   Name   | Familiyname |   provider    |
+----------+-------------+---------------+
| Karl     | Dope        | gmail.com     |
| Jonathan | Dorianius   | hotmail.com   |
| Mary     | Jane        | spiderman.com |
+----------+-------------+---------------+
```

now i want to generate a fourth column, that generates a combination. looking up on google i only found concat, which i can't use since i use sql server 2008.

in the end it should look like this:

```
+----------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
|   Name   | Familiyname |   provider    |             mail              |
+----------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
| Karl     | Dope        | gmail.com     | Karl.Dope@gmail.com           |
| Jonathan | Dorianius   | hotmail.com   | Jonathan.Doranius@hotmail.com |
| Mary     | Jane        | spiderman.com | Mary.Jane@spiderman.com       |
+----------+-------------+---------------+-------------------------------+
```

any ideas or tips?

Comment: Try using + operator

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: Generate an e-mail? But would a generated e-mail even be correct?  It could be 'MaryJane@spiderman.com' or  'mary.jane@spiderman.com'  or  'MJ.Parker@spiderman.com'  or something else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate two SQL fields with text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979909/concatenate-two-sql-fields-with-text)

Answer (score 0):

First way

```
Select Name + Familiyname +'@' + provider As EmailAddress from @tblName
```

SecondWay

```
Select Name  +'@' + provider As EmailAddress from @tblName
```

ThirdWay

```
Select Name +'_' + Familiyname +'@' + provider As EmailAddress from @tblName
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `COALESCE()` to create a null safe e-mail address.

(If both name and Familiyname are non null, return `name.Familiyname@provider`. If only name is non null, return `name@provider`, or if only Familiyname is non null, return `Familiyname@provider`.)

```
select coalesce(name + '.' + Familiyname, name, Familiyname) + '@' + provider As EmailAddress
from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact values in your output, and assuming the email will always be name.familiyname@provider then:

```
Select Name, Familiyname, provider, Name + '.' + Familiyname + '@' + 
provider As mail from tablename
```

For the output that you are expecting, this should do the trick

Answer (score -1):

you can use mysql CONCAT() function :

```
select *, CONCAT(name,'.',Familiyname,"@",provider) as mailAddress from tab;
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=818498f21f1e5cf55d2508eb97558bde)

Comment: Not MySql, and he's looking for a solution that doesn't use CONCAT (not in his MS Sql Version)

Comment: this id judt edit befor edit it was correct before it was mysql now it become sqlserve